# How to delete a file after sending it in a web app?

Tags: java, spring, file, web-applications, file-upload

I have a web application. I am using java and spring. The application can create a file and send it to the browser, this is working fine. The way I do it is:

I create the file in a Services class, and the method returns the address to the controller. The controller then sends the file, and it is downloaded correctly. The code for the controller method is this.

```
@RequestMapping("/getFile")
public @ResponseBody
FileSystemResource getFile() {

    String address = Services.createFile();
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return new FileSystemResource(new File (address));
}
```

The problem is that the file is saved in the server, and after many requests it will have a lot of files. I have to delete them manually. The question is: How can I delete this file after sending it? or Is there a way to send the file without saving it in the server?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't use `@ResponseBody`. Have Spring inject the `HttpServletResponse` and write directly to its `OutputStream`.

```
@RequestMapping("/getFile")
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    String address = Services.createFile();
    File file = new File(address);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

    // copy from in to out
    IOUtils.copy(in,out);

    out.close();
    in.close();
    file.delete();
}
```

I haven't added any exception handling. I leave that to you.

`FileSystemResource` is really just is a wrapper for `FileInputStream` that's used by Spring.

Or, if you want to be hardcore, you could make your own `FileSystemResource` implementation with its own `getOutputStream()` method that returns your own implementation of `FileOutputStream` that deletes the underlying file when you call `close()` on it.

Comment: This solution is problematic when the file is very large. IOUtils.copy(in,out) throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: As far as I see, this doesn't do a zero-copy, unlike FileSystemResource?

Comment: @LakatosGyula It's been a while, but iirc, Spring MVC will use `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` to serialize the `FileSystemResource` to the response stream. It essentially does what `IOUtils.copy` does here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are indeed right! Also, as far as I see a zero-copy is not possible with Spring MVC, only with Webflux. I learned something new.

Comment: You can also use `org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(in, out)` and I'm not sure `out` must be closed because it prevents others from using it later.

Answer (score 12):

So I decided to take Sotirious's suggestion for a "hardcore" way. It is pretty simple, but has one problem. If user of that class opens input stream once to check something and closes it, it will not be able to open it again since file is deleted on close. Spring does not seem to do that, but you will need to check after every version upgrade.

```
public class DeleteAfterReadeFileSystemResource extends FileSystemResource {
    public DeleteAfterReadeFileSystemResource(File file) {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new DeleteOnCloseFileInputStream(super.getFile());
    }

    private static final class DeleteOnCloseFileInputStream extends FileInputStream {

        private File file;
        DeleteOnCloseFileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException    {
            super(file);
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A minor adaption to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326148/2553215).

Using a `InputStreamResource` instead of `FileSystemResource` makes this a little shorter.

```
public class CleanupInputStreamResource extends InputStreamResource {
    public CleanupInputStreamResource(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileInputStream(file) {
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                super.close();
                Files.delete(file.toPath());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, Spring will not handle range headers for InputStreamResources, only for FileSystemResources

Comment: I had to modify your class to add "@Override
        public long contentLength() throws IOException {
            return file.length();
        }" Otherwise it throws an exception because it tries to open twice the inputstream.

Answer (score 5):

You can write Mag's solution with anonymous classes like this:

```
new FileSystemResource(file) {
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new FileInputStream(file) {
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                super.close();
                Files.delete(file.toPath());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326148/4861041) and added some modification. Working so far. Due to my limited knowledge I couldn't create dynamic proxy for my custom inputStream.

```
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

public final class AutoDeleteFileSystemResource extends FileSystemResource {

    public AutoDeleteFileSystemResource(Path filePath) {
        super(filePath);
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    private static final class AutoDeleteStream extends InputStream {

        private final File file;
        private final InputStream original;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return original.read();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            original.close();
            deleteQuietly(file);
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            return original.available();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return original.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return original.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            return original.skip(n);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return original.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return original.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
            original.mark(readlimit);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean markSupported() {
            return original.markSupported();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
            original.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return original.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource#getInputStream()
     */
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new AutoDeleteStream(getFile(), super.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way using [StreamingResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html) from your controller method:

```java
File file = getFile();
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(headers)
    .contentLength(length)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    .body(os -> {
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
        Files.delete(file.toPath());
    });
```

The lambda is shorthand for the following:

```java
new StreamingResponseBody() {
    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
        Files.delete(file.toPath());
    }
}
```