# How to delete a file after sending to user in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8

How can I delete a file automatically after I send the file to user as response?

I'm using Spring MVC 5

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@RequestParam String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File tempLocation = new File("tmp/" + fileName);
        myservice.downloadObject(fileName, tempLocation);

        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(downloaded));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                             .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + downloaded.getName())
                             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                             .contentLength(downloaded.length())
                             .body(resource);
    }
```

Comment: In my opinion it's better you doing it in other thread I mean other time. I think it decreases the work time. so you can define a schedule method to do this in other time that it has little load on your services.

Comment: what is downloadObject doing?

Comment: Please try the solution in this link. This works!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933508/how-to-delete-a-file-after-sending-it-in-a-web-app