# Deleting file after a zero-copy response in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

In Spring Webflux, I want to return a file with a [zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) operation, then after the request is finished, delete the file.

Initially, I wanted to return a FileSystemResource then override the `getInputStream()` method and delete the file on the `InputStream`'s `close()` call. Like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70481055/1420715). Unfortunately, as far as I understand the `Files.delete()` method, this would block.

Then, I looked into the `WebFilter` class, but that doesn't work, because the response was not sent when the filter is being called.

I want to do a zero-copy because I'm low on CPU resources already + I need to support a high-throughput scenario with the lowest amount of resources used.

I feel that I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: Whoever added a -1 to the question, can you please at least provide a reason why you did it?

Comment: could you explain your use case in more details. How do you get file and what operation do you need to perform on file? Do you use WebClient to download file from some external resource and then expose it using Spring Webflux endpoint?

Comment: @Alex I'm creating a very simple web server that has two endpoints. A post one that stores a file, and a delete one that returns the file and then deletes it. It is supposed to be a "staging" area between various processes for files that are too big to send through a queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebFlux provides `ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage` that has support for "zero-copy" file transfers.

As for delete operation, in case your are using `Files.delete` from `java.nio.file` it doesn't look blocking. The best way to determine whether operation is blocking or not is to use [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) in your tests and no blocking calls were detected in my tests.

Therefore the endpoint to perform zero-=copy download could look like the following

```
@GetMapping("/download/{file_name}")
public Mono<Void> download(@PathVariable(name = "file_name") String fileName, ServerHttpResponse response)  {
    ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage zeroCopyResponse = (ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage) response;
    response.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

    var file = getFile(fileName);
    return zeroCopyResponse.writeWith(file, 0, file.length())
            .then(deleteFile(file));
}

private Mono<Void> deleteFile(File file) {
    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }).then();
}
```

In case you need to run some blocking operation as a part of your reactive flow, you need to run it on a separate scheduler. For more info check [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

```
Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        ...
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! Exactly what I need. Just created a bounty with 100 points. Will award it as soon as I can (needs 24 hours before can be awarded).