# How to delete files correctly using webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

method for deleting a file:
(idea warns that problems may occur)

```
 private Mono<Boolean> remove(String path, String fileName) {
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    try {
//Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation 
                        Files.delete(Path.of(path + fileName));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Is there a correct way to delete a file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting file after a zero-copy response in Spring Webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718706/deleting-file-after-a-zero-copy-response-in-spring-webflux) (bit broader than your question, but the answer seems applicable here too)